# How to select only Sprints 1-3 for a combobox?

Tags: combobox, iteration, release, rally

I am working on a Rally app and one of the requirements of the app is to display features committed to in the first 3 sprints of a PSI, but not display features committed to in the 4th sprint. I have tried looking at examples of code involving filters and queries but none of them worked for me. I was thinking of making a combobox where you could select like "PSI 40, Sprint 1-3", that kind of thing but I don't know how to go about doing that. Maybe make a combobox for start date and one for end date but the user can only select sprints ending in "-1" for the start date and "-3" for the end date? The problem is I don't know how to set up that time frame. Also, I was able to access all the iterations that ended in "-1" (for example, Sprint 43-1") but there were multiple because there was a new one for each team.

If someone knows how to do this in a fairly simple way (I am very new to Rally app development and don't understand the more complex code just yet) that would be great. Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Features have no built in way of knowing they are related to sprints. You would have to have a custom field to indicate that. Features go into "Releases" and those are generally used to define the complete PSI.

The major problem you are going to hit is the one you hinted at towards the end of the first paragraph. The Agile Central way of dealing with timeboxes is to create an individual "Iteration" (or "Release") artefact for each project hierarchy node. If each team connects workitem artefacts to a timebox, the UI normally shows them the timeboxes in their own team node.

This means that you need to have some funky (JavaScript?) code to look at dates of timeboxes and then collect them together and use the list as a filter for the fetch of the workitems.

You cannot really rely on the name being consistent unless you enforce it, most strictly, manually. What would happen if one of the teams decided that their naming convention for the timeboxes should be different?

If you enforce naming conventions and also enforce that the timeboxes are only ever manipulated (created, updated, etc.) at the 'root' node, you could get away with selecting workitem artefacts that have been attached to timeboxes by fetching workitems into a store and defining filters along the lines of:  Release._refObjectName = timeBoxName

Another upshot of having to enforce these rules is that you can then do a fetch for timeboxes in the 'root' node only by setting the context: { projectScopeUp: false, projectScopeDown: false }, order them by start date and choose the first three names.